# What is the best way to draw realtime spectrum in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, fft, draw

Two or three timees a second my program receives data from LAN for spectrum. This data is a result of FFT. I need to redraw spectrum as fast as possible and show it in real time. Now I have an application on C++ Builder that does this work but draw it point by point on canvas, or smth like this... It's too slow. Moreover from time to time I need to load spectrum from file and shift the picture.

Question: Now I need to rewrite such program on .NET. What is the best way to reach this goal?

What is the best technology? WPF,XNA, or just GDI?

Where can I find an exmaple?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking essentially "How can I efficiently draw 2D graphics in C#"? Because *what* you're drawing doesn't matter. It seems like you just have an issue with rendering 2D graphics of *some form* in real time.

Comment: IMO it's what you're most comfortable with. For me, I choose WPF if first I couldn't find something open-source that already does it. Doesn't a bar graph work?

Comment: I found out that WPF is not that fast as I expected. The fasted way I could find(except shaders, raw directx, ogl,...) was the GDI by interop.

Answer (score -1):

So, as a result of my investigation, fast redrawing an image and moving it using margins was one of the best choice.

To speed up Image creating LockBits was used

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx

[C# LockBits perfomance (int[,] to byte[])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535812/c-sharp-lockbits-perfomance-int-to-byte)

Comment: you really want to draw a spectrum by setting each pixel by pointers,...?

Comment: Probably I didn't correctly describe the goal... I need to draw sonogram :) And I really do it pixel by pixel and don't imagine another way...